# Reading from serial port in Java

Tags: java

Hi I am reading data from a multimeter and I have to store those values in float. I am using javax.comm jar file for it and Serial port. But after reading from it I am getting values like

> [B@1592174 [B@a352a5 [B@86fe26 [B@97a560 ...

And when I am converting these values to string and the to double I am getting some huge number which is not same as the value in the multimeter. So what should I do??

I am doing the reading from the serial port via inputStream and converting them to a byte array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to print an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the actual `byte[]` object, whose `toString` shows you the class (`[B` for byte array) and the hash code (`a352a5`, for example). Instead, use `Arrays.toString(byteArray)`.

Comment: I have used Arrays.toString(byteArray), but it is printing an array which consist of singned integers. And those values does'nt matches with my multimeter values.

Comment: the value for [B@86fe26 is

[-16, 120, -16, -128, -128, 112, -128, -16, -128, -8, 112, 120, -16, -128, -8, 120, -8, -16, 0, 112, -128, 0, -8, 0, -8, 0, 0, 120, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0....]

as my byteArray size is 1024....

Comment: @user3335924 Now you have to interpret those bytes according to your multimeter's protocol, which you haven't described at all. Using a `ByteBuffer` wrapped around your array and calling `getFloat` might work if it's IEEE 754.